# Casting from std::size_t to void

Tags: c++, casting

In a lot of older code, I've seen variations on the following snippet:

```
std::size_t  some_size = some_function_that_returns_size_t();
(void)some_size;
assert(some_size > some_other_size);
```

What is the purpose of the cast to `void`?

**Bear in mind this is not casting to `void*`**

If I has to guess, this looks like a safety check to ensure that the machine size_t is larger than a void at compile time.

Playing around in an interpreter reveals that the cast will return a value different than `some_size` if the initial value is large enough, but since it's not being assigned, I honestly don't see the point.

In case it matters, this was found in an allocation library as part of the allocation checks against alignment and size.

Comment: `assert` will be wiped out in release builds and then `some_size` will generate a warning because of _unused local variable_. Casting to void has no effect and it'll suppress that warning. Often that's encapsulated in macros like `UNUSED_PARAMETER(x)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know such a trick is used to prevent the compiler to issue a warning that a variable was defined but was not used.

Comment: It prevents some compilers, not all.

Comment: @Jarod42 Maybe. But I do not see any other reason to use such a line of code.

Comment: Do you think that the compiler will optimize away the statement? I would guess that for release builds, it would be better to set the `no_variable_set_but_unused` flag, but maybe this is better for a case-by-case situation...?

Comment: I agree with you for the purpose, I just warn that it doesn't work for all compilers. The clean way is to define a function like `template <typename T> void UnusedArg(const T&/* No name */) {}`